# SMO Backup fails with error 1827 (full database)

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, smo

I am using an SqlExpress 2012 (I have to, no other choice).
The database runs full under some rare circumstances.
Now I want to make a backup of the full database and then truncate some tables and shrink back the database.
For the backup I use the following code:

```
public void BackupDatabase(string backupFilePath, string databaseServer, string databaseName, out string errorMessage)
{
    var connection = new ServerConnection(databaseServer);
    connection.StatementTimeout = 360;
    Backup backup = new Backup();
    backup.Devices.AddDevice(backupFilePath, DeviceType.File);
    backup.Database = databaseName;
    backup.Initialize = true;
    backup.Incremental = false;
    backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    backup.SqlBackup(new Server(connection));
}
```

But if I do that, I get an error after some time. This is my error log:

> 2020-01-20 13:42:54.89 spid10s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
>   2020-01-20 13:42:54.90 spid12s     Starting up database
>   'mssqlsystemresource'.
>  2020-01-20 13:42:54.91 spid12s     The
>   resource database build version is 12.00.6108. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:42:54.93 spid12s     Starting up database 'model'.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:42:55.69 spid12s     Clearing tempdb database.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:00.07 spid12s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:00.37 spid18s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or
>   stopped state.
>  2020-01-20 13:43:00.37 spid18s     The Database
>   Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:00.39 spid18s     Service Broker manager has started.
>   2020-01-20 13:43:01.02 spid10s     Recovery is complete. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:02.66 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality
>   initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:15.65 spid51      Starting up database 'TESTDB'.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:43:36.75 spid51      Error: 1827, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2020-01-20 13:43:36.75 spid51      CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE
>   failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed
>   your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
>  2020-01-20
>   13:49:04.59 Backup      Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2020-01-20 13:49:04.59 Backup      BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE PHASIS. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages.
>  2020-01-20 14:14:56.76 Backup      Error: 3041,
>   Severity: 16, State: 1.
>  2020-01-20 14:14:56.76 Backup      BACKUP
>   failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE PHASIS. Check the
>   backup application log for detailed messages.

It seems to me that the spid51 tries to do a "CREATE DATABASE" after collecting all infos. But then it tries to make the backup file as part of the server instance and that crashes because the 10 GB cannot increase anymore.
Has someone an idea on how to alter the backup, so that the backup is not counted anymore against the database limit? Maybe explicitly give it a new database or something the like?

The infos of Microsoft regarding the SMO is not really helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-smo-140.17283.0

edit: When I do a backup with the Management Studio it works, but I have to do it with smo programmatically.

Comment: Looks like you've reached the maximum size limit for a database on express.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem, but what is the workaround? I dont want to expend the database anymore, only make a backup before I truncate the tables.

Comment: There is no "work around". If you need larger database you need a paid version of SQL Server.

Comment: I dont need a larger database only a backup of the full one.

Comment: You can't attach a database larger than 10GB in express, so you need a full version to be able to do that.

Comment: I think I made myself a little bit unclear here, but the database IS mounted in an instance and it is still running (as long as I dont try to insert any more data).

Comment: The problem is even altering the database, to begin the backup, will increase the size (could be as tiny as a couple of bytes). You'll need to make it smaller first

Comment: But why can the Microsoft SQL Management Studio (which uses the same dll) do a backup without exceeding the limit? I guess that my smo object is not correctly configured. There has to be a setting, another object or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that is... erm... a little bit embarassing.
I raised the timeout from 360 (6 minutes) to 3600 (60 minutes) and it didn't crash anymore. So the log entries and error messages were only really confusing and lead me astray.